# Why i have to use httpContextAccessor in Asp.Net to get user name and role?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

I'm new in asp.net and I'm watching a course to learn it.

In this course `httpContextAccessor` was used to get the userName and it's Role.
But I can't find the reason behind using it. I can call the global "User" and get the data without using httpContext like the below.

```
var role = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Role);
var name = User.Identity.Name;
```

instead of

```
_LoginUserId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
_Userrole =httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Role);
```

Why i have to use `httpContextAccessor` in Asp.Net to get user name and role?

Answer (score 0):

the main reason behind HttpContextAccessor is to avail httpcontext inside service as User is connected to http context and only available in the web project unless assemblies are added explicitly in libraries, check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-5.0) link for more details.